# What is this empty black bar on the top called, and how can I get rid of it?

Tags: android, sdk

I am targeting api 10. On my droid maxx (4.4) there is this clickable but empty bar that appears on the side of the screen as seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSjmk.jpg . On my Nexus S (4.1.2) the bar is not present. On my friends Nexus 4 (4.4) he has a bar, but it contains the phones main buttons, the nexus 4 doesn't have off-screen buttons as mine does.

If I target api19, the bar goes away on my droid maxx, obviously thats not really a solution.

The bar renders on top of my application, and is just visually undesirable, so it's a real problem. What this bar is called and how I can get rid of it? Thanks.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="net.logicaldreams.edensharbor2"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">

    <application android:label="@string/app_name"
                 android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                 android:allowBackup="true" >

        <activity android:name="edensharbor2"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                  android:launchMode="singleTask"
                  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
                  >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: What is the problem with setting target API to 19?

Comment: I didn't mean specifically the manifests target tag only, I mean setting everything to 19, building for 19 only. Naturally that's not an option because I want the game to run on as many devices as possible. If I do only set the targetSdkVersion at 19, there are other problems, namely that the application closes on an orientation change.

Comment: "If I do only set the targetSdkVersion at 19, there are other problems, namely that the application closes on an orientation change" -- so... fix that bug in your app, and you have your solution.

Comment: The orientation change shutting down the application is as I understand it expected behavior on api<=12 when targetsdkversion is above 12 because higher api's require android:configChanges="screenSize" in addition to orientation to prevent that behavior. However ant will fail if you include it because your sdk target is set at 10.